# SciFi book in English translated from French circa 1970-1980

Tags: story-identification

Can anyone help, please? in the 80's I read a SciFi in English, translated from French about a 'current' discovery of a 'perfect couple' in a spherical ship found buried in ice. The girl was revived and talked of an earlier Earth where man lived with nature and took 'energy' pills for food. Eventually the girl takes poison and is hurriedly returned to the ship and 'refrozen.' The ship is abandoned with the hope that some future generation can save them.
It was a well-written full-length book that I would love to re-discover. Thank you in anticipation that one of you special people know the book.

Answer (score 9):

The book is called "[The Ice People](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ice_People_%28Barjavel_novel%29)" (also known as "la Nuit des temps") by French author René Barjavel.

> *Scientists discover a man and woman in suspended animation buried in
>   Arctic ice. They awaken the woman, Elea, who tells the story of
>   herself, her husband Paikan, and their world 900,000 years in the
>   past.*

[image: The Ice People cover]